# Commit to Github using Colab and got: error: pathspec 'commit”' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, google-colaboratory

I'm new to Github.

So following a tutorial I found online, I created a folder containing files and subfolders stored in Google Drive. Then I navigated to Google drive using Google Colab and wrote the following codes:

```
%cd /content/drive/My Drive/blablaProject
!git init
!git config --global user.email "blablabla@protonmail.com"
!git config --global user.name "blabla"
!git add -A
!git commit -m “first commit”
```

Then I got the following error:

```
error: pathspec 'commit”' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

UPDATE:

Ok I think that might be the issue here, the curly brackets... But I did something after this, I run the following codes:

```
 import os
 os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/blablaProject")
 !git clone https://github.com/blablabla/blabla.git
```

So now, after restarted the session and removing the curly bracket and rerun, I got:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/content/drive/My Drive/ift6760Project/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

Comment: I did, I forgot to write it in the question.

Comment: ok I think that was an error, I didn't know what you were talking about before. But I still have some error now

Comment: OK so I solved the problem you originally posed, and you just change the question to ask about a different problem. I can't get behind that, sorry. And the error message _tells_ you what to do, just do it. And remember what I said earlier, git on a google drive is not going to work; they are opposites.